# Что означает именно такой big O: O(|E|)

Tags: математика, графы, сложность

Проходил тест по [BIG O](https://bigoquiz.com/question?quiz-id=bigo&question-id=incidence-matrix-query) и попался такой вопрос:

Incidence Matrix  -> [Матрица инцидентности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

> ```
> Graph Operations: Incidence Matrix
> Query
>
> O(|V| + |E|)
> O(1)
> O(|E|) -> правильный ответ
> O(|V|)
> O(|V|²)
> O(|V| ⋅ |E|)
> ```

Вопрос что означает такой big O: `O(|E|)`?

[Тут](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) же, например, нету такой сложности.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Такие Big O типичны для алгоритмов на графах.

Классические обозначения:

- `|V|` - количество вершин в графе (`V`—от английского "**v**ertices"— это множество вершин)
- `|E|` - количество ребер в графе (`E`—от английского "**e**dges"—это множество парных вершин, также называемых ребрами)

Таким образом, `O(|E|)` будет означать что алгоритм имеет линейную сложность в зависимости от количества ребер графа.

[По приведенной ссылке](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) находятся примеры алгоритмов, которые не относятся к алгоритмам на графах, и большинство из них использует `n` в качестве размера "исходных данных". Типичный пример — количество элементов в списке\дереве\любой другой структуре данных.

Для алгоритмов на графах, типичны два очень разных параметра "исходных данных": количество вершин и количество ребер, и вычислительную сложность (Big O) очень полезно раскладывать на эти составляющие.

---

NB:

По определению, граф — это упорядоченная пара `G(V,E)`. Таким образом, `|V|` - есть [мощность множества вершин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), а `|E|` - есть [мощность множества ребер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0),  где мощность нужно понимать как абстрактное обобщение над "количеством элементов множества".

Comment: Добавлю, что на английском вершины и рёбра — это **V**ertices и **E**dges соответственно

Comment: @nomnoms12 отличное замечание.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, что за реинкарнация? Мне помнится, вы тут давно и у вас были совсем другие показатели репы.

Comment: @avp нет, показатели всегда были такими. Я не так много отвечаю на Ru.SO. Для меня "родной" сайт - Computational Science, где я модератор.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, значит ошибся (с репой), но помню ваши отличные ответы.

Comment: @AntonMenshov а это |x| символ абсолютной величины я так понял. Или не верно?

Comment: @Demon__ добавил пояснение в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Есть алгоритм. Он принимает на вход ряд параметров: a, b, c...

Алгоритм работает за время t(a, b, c, ...).

Говорят, что алгоритм работает за O(f(a, b, c, ...)), если существует такая константа C, что для любых a, b, c, ... имеем неравенство:

t(a, b, c, ...)<C*f(a, b, c, ...)

В твоем случае a=E, b=V, f=|E|